# Modules imported in index.js using KrakenJS is undefined in other files

Tags: node.js, passport.js

In my index.js file I require some libraries that is needed for my application.

```
var kraken = require('kraken-js'),
    app = {},
    db = require('./lib/database'),
    passport = require('passport'),
    User = require('./models/user'),
    auth = require('./lib/auth');
```

However, in other files that are using these libs they seem to be invisible and I don't understand why since it should be available in the underlaying scopes?

I have a controller called login.js which looks like this:

```
var LoginModel = require('../models/login');


module.exports = function (app) {

    var model = new LoginModel();


    app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
         //Include any error messages that come from the login process.
        model.messages = req.flash('error');
        res.render('login', model);
    });

    app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook'));

    app.get('/auth/facebook/callback', passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/login' }), function(req, res) {
        // Successful authentication, redirect home.
        res.redirect('/');
    });

    app.get('/logout', function (req, res) {
        req.logout();
        res.redirect('/');
    });

};
```

and I think this is the file that outputs `[ReferenceError: passport is not defined]` (since nothing else is reported) when I'm trying to run the application with `npm start`. To be frankly honest I don't understand how the controller is even initiated and that could be the cause of why I don't understand this problem.

I would like to import everything I need just once if possible but I find myself using require way more than I wish for. If anyone with good knowledge with KrakenJS / Express could explain how to setup this for easier access or why I need to require stuff even if they are required in the start of the application I would be terrible happy.

Comment: Looking at the example code I'm going after I can see that they added require('passport'); in the login controller. But it just feels unnecessary and wonder if it could be solved in another way.

Comment: Side note,
Kraken has a passport example. It may help you with your project, beyond the scope of this particular question:
https://github.com/lmarkus/Kraken_Example_Passport/

Comment: Yeah I used that one a bit as ground for my implementation :) But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have misunderstood the Node.js module system slightly. You must `require` a module in every file it is used in. This is necessary to have access to the module via a variable assignment (think of each module as a clean slate).

This is not as inefficient as it looks. The first `require` reads the module from the file system, and evaluates it. Each subsequent `require` of the same module simply returns a reference to the already evaluated module.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I'm trying to really wrap my head around node more deeply than before and at the same time dig into different libraries.